# How do I Animate Back to an Original Image with JQuery

Tags: jquery, animation

I've got a jQuery slider with two images, I'd like the first image to slide back in so it is on a permanent loop.

I have link to the a pen here https://codepen.io/emilychews/pen/ENbbqW

My code is:

HTML

```
<div id="slider">
<ul class="slides">
    <li class="slide"><img src="images/img1.jpg" alt="slideone"></li>
    <li class="slide"><img src="images/img2.jpg" alt="slidetwo"></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var slider = $('#slider'),
  slides = $('#slider .slides'),
  slide = $('.slide'),
  currentSlide = 0;

setInterval (function(){
$(slides).animate({'margin-left': '-=266.5px' }, 1000, function(){
        currentSlide++;
          if (currentSlide === slides.length) {
              currentSlide = 0;
              slides.css('margin-left', 0);
          }
  });

}, 3000);

});
```

I have set it so the original slide goes back to the first image with margin-left: 0, but I can't work out to get this to happen so that it animates in from the right. At the moment when slide2 gets into position slide1 just appears immediately without the 3 second delay of the setInterval() function, or the animation itself.

Any help would be awesome.

Emily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways to do infinite slider.

**Firstly**, when the shown one turn left and disappear, you should append it to the parent node.

But by this way, you should keep `.slides` enough width to keep more li(s) when time slip.

```
// CSS
#slider .slides {
  display: block;
  height: 400px;
  width: 1000000px; /*enough width to keep slides*/
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
// JS
setInterval (function(){
  $(slides).animate({'margin-left': '-=266.5px'}, 1000, function(){
    $('.slide').eq(currentSlide).clone().appendTo($('#slider .slides'))
    // Maybe you need to give .slides new width here
    currentSlide++
  });
}, 3000);
```

By this way, you could understand my sloution, but the code maybe a little ugly, so I will give you the next plan.

**Secondly**, just use the li(s) you keep to be infinite slider.

```
// HTML
// use .slide1 .slide2 be more clear
<ul class="slides">
    <li class="slide slide1">1</li>
    <li class="slide slide2">2</li>
</ul>
// CSS
#slider .slides {
  display: block;
  height: 400px;
  width: 566px; /*total width of both slides*/
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.slide1 {
  background-color: red;
  height: 400px;
  width: 266.5px;
}
.slide2 {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 400px;
  width: 266.5px;
}
// JS
setInterval (function(){
  $(slides).animate({'margin-left': '-=266.5px'}, 1000, function(){
    $('.slide').eq(0).appendTo($('#slider .slides'))
    $('#slider .slides').css('margin-left', 0)
  });
}, 3000);
```

What I do just, when the animation finished:

1. make the disapper in left one to the tail of parent.
2. then make `margin-left: 0` of the parent

so it looks like the loop keeps infinite.

But take care:

In the callback function of `.animate()`, **you should use `$('.slide')` to `slide` that you saved before**. Because the jQuery selector in memory will diff from the truth.

Here is the full code:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

var slider = $('#slider'),
    slides = $('#slider .slides'),
    slide = $('.slide'),
    currentSlide = 0;

setInterval (function(){
  $(slides).animate({'margin-left': '-=266.5px' }, 1000, function(){
  $('.slide').eq(0).appendTo($('#slider .slides'))
  $(slides).css('margin-left', 0)
  });

}, 3000);

});
```

```css
#slider {
position: relative;
height: 400px;
width: 266.5px;
overflow: hidden; /*hides overflow of child elements*/
margin-top: 100px;
margin-bottom: 100px;
margin-left: 100px;
}

#slider .slides {
  display: block;
  height: 400px;
  width: 566px; /*total width of both slides*/
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;}

#slider .slide {
  list-style-type: none;
  float: left;
}

.slide1 {
 background-color: red;
 height: 400px;
width: 266.5px;
}
.slide2 {
 background-color: blue;
 height: 400px;
width: 266.5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<body>
<div id="slider">
    <ul class="slides">
        <li class="slide slide1">1</li>
        <li class="slide slide2">2</li>
    </ul>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks Tomlsion. I really appreciate your help !

Answer (score 0):

You can check this updates, it will do the job, also I've added one more slide to check the solution on many slides

There are two ways to scroll to the first slide, I've highlighted both ways in the code

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

var slider = $('#slider'),
    slides = $('#slider .slides'),
    slide = $('.slide'),
    currentSlide = 0;

 setInterval (function(){ 
    currentSlide=currentSlide+1;
    if(currentSlide == slide.length)
    {
        currentSlide=0;  
        /* in case you want the first slide to just pop up un-comment this line
        $(".slides").css('margin-left','0px'); */
        /* in case you want to scroll to the first slide use this */
        $(".slides").animate({'margin-left': '0px' }, 2000);
    }
    else
    {  
      $(".slides").animate({'margin-left': '-=266.5px' }, 2000);
    }
   
  },3000);
  
});
```

```css
#slider {
position: relative;
height: 400px;
width: 266.5px;
overflow: hidden; /*hides overflow of child elements*/
margin-top: 100px;
margin-bottom: 100px;
margin-left: 100px;
}

.slides {
  display: block;
  height: 400px;
  width: 799.5px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;}

.slide {
  list-style-type: none;
  float:left;
}

.slide:nth-child(1) {
 background-color: red;
 height: 400px;
width: 266.5px;
}
.slide:nth-child(2) {
 background-color: blue;
 height: 400px;
 width: 266.5px;
}
.slide:nth-child(3) {
 background-color: green;
 height: 400px;
 width: 266.5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="slider">
    <ul class="slides">
        <li id="1" class="slide"><img src="images/img1.jpg" alt="slideone"></li>
        <li id="2" class="slide"><img src="images/img2.jpg" alt="slidetwo"></li>
        <li id="3" class="slide"><img src="images/img3.jpg" alt="slidethree"></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you Doaa.  I'll run through it when I get back to the office